# Lightning Service Console : Issue facing on open a new subtab in Lightning service console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, service-cloud-console

We were using standard lightning component `force:workspaceAPI` for opening new subtab in Service console. It was working fine till this morning.But now it showing below error:

> No COMPONENT named workspaceAPI found

Please anyone guide us how to open subtab in Lightning service console. We tried also `force:workspaceAPIAccess` but no luck

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <force:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <lightning:button label="Open Tab" onclick="{! c.openTab }" />
</aura:component>
({
    openTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspace = component.find("workspace"); 
        workspace.openTab({
            url: '/sObject/001R0000003HgssIAC/view', 
            focus: true,  
            callback : function(error, response) { 
                workspace.focusTab({tabId : response});  
            }
        });
    },
})
```

Comment: is this resolved, seems this doesn't work as in the docs

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed now. Please note that the component name changed from

```
<force:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
```

to

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
```